# Fragments in viewpager

Tags: android, android-viewpager

I have viewpager with some fragments and i set to each fragment my model class according which UI of fragment should be edited. That model class i set to fragment at constructor before i add that fragment to FragmentStatePagerAdapter. My problem is that after rotating screen or when system kills my application and i restore it, my fragment are recreated by system and my model class instance is lost. Even if I set new FragmentStatePagerAdapter, fragments created by system are visible. Is there any right way of achive that i create new instances of my fragments and place them into viewpager? I tried so many thinks like removing fragments from FragmentManager, adding Adapter to viewpager again, change FragmentStatePagerAdapter only to FragmentPagerAdapter and nothing helped.

My activity class with loading model classes in loader from some resource:

```
        List<Fragment> visibleFragment = new ArrayList<Fragment>();
        for (Screen screen : wizard.screens) {
            if (screen.visible) {
                visibleFragment.add(new ScreenUI(screen));
            }
        }
        viewPager.setAdapter(null);
        viewPager.setAdapter(new WizardPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager(), visibleFragment));
```

My FragmentStatePagerAdapter

```
public class WizardPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
private final List<Fragment> mFragments;
private final int count;

public WizardPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm, List<Fragment> fragments) {
    super(fm);
    mFragments = fragments;
    count = mFragments.size();
}

@Override
public Fragment getItem(int index) {
    return mFragments.get(index);
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return count;
}
}
```

Comment: activity is reloading on screen orientation changes?

Comment: Have you added screenSize in your activity element in Manifest file? It will prevent activity recreation in screen rotation. And also in your fragment constructor, be sure to check if view is not null.

Comment: yes, activity is reloading and fragment lifecycle methods like onCreateView and onResume are called before the loader finished. I dont want to add configurationChanges to manifest file

Answer (score 1):

try add in Manifest  android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize" to activity.

OR something like that

```
public class ViewPagerTaskAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
Map<Integer, FragmentViewTask> fragmentsTask = new HashMap<Integer, FragmentViewTask>();
@Override
    public Fragment getItem(int arg0) {
        FragmentViewTask myFragment = FragmentViewTask.newInstance(arg0,
                tasks.get(arg0));
        fragmentsTask.put(arg0, myFragment);
        return myFragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position, Object object) {
        super.destroyItem(container, position, object);
        fragmentsTask.remove(position);
    }
        public FragmentViewTask getFragment(int key) {
        return fragmentsTask.get(key);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        if (tasks != null)
            return tasks.size();

        return 0;
    }

}
```

Comment: Its not general solution to forbid system config changes

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `onRetainInstance(true)` on your `Fragments`?

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setRetainInstance(true);    
}
```

Comment: Yea, that solves problem when screen orientation is changed, but not problem when system kill my app.